# SonarLint bind SonarQube

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

Tenho o SonarQube na versão 6.2 instalado em um servidor.

No meu computador eu tenho o Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) instalado. Através do Eclipse Marketplace, instalei no Eclipse o SonarLint 2.6.0.

Na view SonarQube Servers eu fiz a configuração do servidor e testei a conexão com sucesso, e fiz o bind dos projetos.

No entanto, as issues do Sonar que aparecem no servidor não estão aparecendo no Eclipse. E quando eu retiro o bind dos projetos, aparecem issues no Eclipse, mas que não são as mesmas do servidor.

Como faço para as issues do SonarQube do servidor aparecerem no Eclipse?